# How to run Kestrel behind IIS

Tags: iis, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, port, kestrel

I have a problem in running an asp.net core website on remote server.
I want to use kestrel with IIS ,and published it in visual studio 2017
It's my program.cs:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseUrls("http://example.com")
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .Build();
host.Run();
}
```

At the remote server when I double click on myWebAppName.exe the kestrel run and very fast closed
What i must do?
pleas, help me

Answer (score 4):

First of all: you don't need to click on app .exe file if you want to host in IIS. Doing this you run it as a standalone application. Instead you should create a IIS Website.

---

Configuration via code is only one of steps. You need also configure IIS to host your app. Follow this [Set up a hosting environment for ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS, and deploy to it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis) official documentation to setup everything right.

Note: some steps are different for varied ASP.NET Core versions.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that some unhandled exception is thrown ("app closed very fast"). Open command line (cmd.exe), navigate to your app folder and run .exe from command line - it will not close and you'll see error message.

After you fix bugs (and your app will run on server, not close) - read [Set up a hosting environment for ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS, and deploy to it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis) to know how properly run your app under/behind IIS. In short: IIS will run your .exe itself (when website starts), there is no need to start it manually.